# Getting Error when trying to build using gulp.build command

Tags: node.js, angularjs, node-modules

Getting Below error:

### [error]Gulp failed with error:_tool\node\6.17.1\x64\node.exe failed with return code: 1

and error is showing in console like below:

```
node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts(356,36): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/node/repl.d.ts(362,36): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(21,30): error TS1005: '=' expected.
node_modules/@types/node/util.d.ts(183,30): error TS1005: '=' expected.
```

**Node version:node-v6.17.1-win-x64**

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?